# finding special characters in array of string variables bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, file, grep, special-characters

It's regarding finding words with special characters in a text file and separate them.

For ex: I have a file called `temp.txt` with below values. File can contain `n` number of values but I just mentioned 4 as an example.

```
Ag$thyg
bacde
\RTysdre
stack
```

So, I want values WITHOUT special characters to be stored in another file.

Comment: Define _special characters_.

Comment: basically all...#$<>[]{}`"'\/|$*?;.

Comment: put another way, any non-alphabetic characters, is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sed probably:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]*//g' file
```

This removes every character that is not alpha num OR underscore or hyphen.

But I guess you need to elaborate your definition of special character better.

**EDIT:** As per comments you can use grep:

```
grep -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]' file > newfile
```

OR else:

```
egrep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$' file > newfile
```

Comment: Anubhav.. I don't want to delete special characters from words.. but ignore words having special characters and move words without special characters to new file. In my above example, script should move 2nd and 4th values to new file and ignore 1st and 3rd because those contain special characters.

Comment: perfect.Thanks Anubhav. I have one more question in addition to it. If i have to store words WITH Special characters in another file at same time, can we do it?

Comment: To store special character lines in another file you can do: `grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]' file > specialfile`

Comment: Thanks Anubhav. While testing your first command "grep -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]' file", i see one issue. This will also list empty space also. I mean to say, my input in files are

Comment: Thanks Anubhav. While testing your first command "grep -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]' file", i see one issue. This will also list empty space. I mean to say, In my test.txt file i entered below values  
abace
 
gerrte
gbe$gf
R4#5qw

When i execute "grep -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]' test.txt", it is giving me three values as output.
abace
 
gerrte

That means it is taking empty space also. Ideally command should only take alphabets and numbers and nothing else.

Comment: oh sire you can use: `egrep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$' file > newfile` to ignore empty lines

Comment: I got it.. i used this command and it is working as expected ...grep -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' test.txt | sed -e '/^$/d'

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` like this:

```
tr -d "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" < yourfile
```

and list inside the square braces any extra characters you particularly dislike! At the moment, `tr` will delete (`-d`) anything that is not upper and lower case letters and digits.

If you want to save the output to a new file, do this:

```
tr -d "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" < yourfile > newfile
```